# WSO2 DSS - executing operation on backup database if query failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a problem with making dss use backup database if original one is down. The idea is, there are 2 databases, the second db is the clone of the first one. I want to have operation which is trying to execute query on the first db, if it fais (because for example first db is unavailable ) it tries to execute the same query on the 2nd database. How can I achieve such result?

Comment: I think you have two options here:
1. Use a JDBC driver that has this kind of fail-over capability
2. Use two DSS instances and front them with a proxy that implements the fail-over. This proxy can easily be implemented with WSO2 ESB.

Comment: Or you can have a database cluster.